# change value of string from other activity in java

Tags: java, android, string

I have two classes Class "A" and Class "B". In class A i have declared a 
String password ="admin" .Now in class B i am taking value from user and i 
want to change that value of string in class A and want to store value that 
user entered. How can i do that?   Any help please?

class A

```
 forgetpassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent j = new Intent(MainActivity.this,newpassword.class);
                    startActivity(j);
```

Class B

```
 EditText newpassword;
        Button change;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_password);

            newpassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.newpassword);
            change = (Button)findViewById(R.id.chnage);



            change.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    MainActivity.b= newpassword.getText().toString();

                    Intent y= new Intent(NewPassword.this,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(y);



                }
            });
```

Comment: Is the MainActivity is the class A ?

Comment: no .. just write as an example class A and class B

Comment: name of class A is MAinactivity and class b is newpassword @Rohit Singh

Comment: Main Activity goes to ForgotPassword Activity then ForgotPasswordActivity goes back to MainActivity with new password right ?

Comment: yes right. i have to change the value of string in mainactivity from second activity

Answer (score 1):

### Use StartActivityForResult()

When you intend to get some result back from an Activity you should start activity using `startActivityForResult(intent,requestcode)`

#### Its easy Follow these steps

> StartActivity

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ForgotPasswordActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

> Set new password in ForgotPasswordActivity

Now you are in ForgotPasswordActivity, set your new password and return back to MainActivity on Button click like this.

```
change.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                

                Intent y= new Intent(NewPassword.this,MainActivity.class);
                y.putExtra("someKey",newpassword.getText().toString());   //set new password
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent); // set your result
                finish(); // return back to MainActivity



            }
        });
```

> Retrive new Password in MainActivity

Now you navigated back to MainActivty to retrieve your new password override `onActivityResultMethod()`.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

if (requestCode == 1) {
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        String newPassword=data.getStringExtra("someKey");
    }
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        //Write your code if there's no result
    }
}
}
```

Here a link on [startActivityForResult()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

This can lead to context leaking or NPE when you finish the activity.
Instead use an Application class and initialize the string variable in it and with the use of `getters()` and `setters()` you can access the variable.

```
public class BaseApplication extends android.app.Application{


private String admin;
    @Override
    onCreate(...){
        this.admin = "";
    }

    public String getAdmin(){
        return this.admin;
    }

    public void setAdmin(String admin){
        this.admin = admin;
    }

}
```

classA:

```
...
((BaseApplication) getApplicationContext()).setAdmin("!mpr355!v3");
...
```

classB:

```
...
String myAdmin = ((BaseApplication) getApplicationContext()).getAdmin();
...
```

Also in your manifest file.

`<application`

`android:name=".BaseApplication"`

` ...>

**UPDATE**

Before `startActivity(y);`

just call

`y.putExtra("pass", password);`

and in your MainActivity, call `getIntent().getStringExtra("pass");`

Check for null pointers and you are good to go! :)

Comment: This is not the right way to pass data between activities

Comment: @Sony he does not want to pass data between activities. He wants to have a variable that he can access/change in different activities.

Comment: Either this or a singleton pattern can be used, this I believe is a simpler solution for him.

Answer (score 0):

You can send data from one activity to another in the intent, Use the `putExtra()` methods the intent class to pass data.Send the data like this

```
Intent y= new Intent(NewPassword.this,MainActivity.class);
y.putExtra("yourKey",newpassword.getText().toString())
startActivity(y);
```

and in the `onCreate()` of  `MianActivity` you can retrieve the value using `getStringExtra("yourKey")` like this

```
Intent callingIntent = getIntent();
String password = callingIntent.getStringExtra("yourKey");
```

and use the password.

Or you can start the `NewPassword` activity for a result and get the data back in `onActivityResult()`

```
Intent newPasswordIntent = new Intent(this,NewPassword.class);
startActivityForResult(newPasswordIntent ,REQUEST_CODE);
```

and in the change button click handler,

```
Intent intent= new Intent();
intent.putExtra("yourKey",newpassword.getText().toString());
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    String password = data.getStringExtra("yourKey")
}
```

*Public static variables are easy to call, be aware that they can cause memory leaks*

Answer (score 0):

Muhammad,

There are many ways to do that and some of the listing here,

- Use Broadcast receiver
- Use start activity for result
- Use static variable

From all of this if you want to change much time then I think broadcast receiver is good one,

Here is the example of broadcast receiver,

**In your activity A register broadcast receiver with specific action,**

```
 private BroadcastReceiver brodcastRec=new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if(intent!=null && intent.getAction().equals("changePassword")){
                String newPassword=intent.getStringExtra("newPassword");
                //do whatever you want to do here after getting new password
            }
        }
    };
```

And then after write following code in your on create of activity A

```
IntentFilter intentFilter=new IntentFilter("changePassword");
        registerReceiver(brodcastRec,intentFilter);
```

**And In your activity B or click event of Button**

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
    intent.setAction("changePassword");
    intent.putExtra("newPassword","yourValue");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
```